# Is there a way to use a specific global string cache after running reset_string_cache() in rust polars

Tags: rust, rust-polars

Running below code we get two global string cache as I have used `reset_string_cache()` before creating `out2`.
Is it possible to create another categorical variable with same global string cache as used in `out1` after using `reset_string_cache()`?

```rust
use polars_core::prelude::*;
use polars_core::{reset_string_cache, toggle_string_cache};

fn main() {
    let slice1 = &[
        Some("foo"),
        None,
        Some("bar1"),
        Some("foo"),
        Some("foo"),
        Some("bar1"),
    ];
    let slice2 = &[
        Some("foo"),
        None,
        Some("bar2"),
        Some("foo"),
        Some("foo"),
        Some("bar2"),
    ];

    toggle_string_cache(true);

    let ca1 = Utf8Chunked::new("a", slice1);
    let out1 = ca1.cast(&DataType::Categorical(None)).unwrap();
    let out1 = out1.categorical().unwrap().clone();
    let rev_map_global1 = out1.get_rev_map();
    println!("{:?}", rev_map_global1);

    reset_string_cache();

    let ca2 = Utf8Chunked::new("b", slice2);
    let out2 = ca2.cast(&DataType::Categorical(None)).unwrap();
    let out2 = out2.categorical().unwrap().clone();
    let rev_map_global2 = out2.get_rev_map();
    println!("{:?}", rev_map_global2);
}
```